# Select features with click AND double-click in Openlayers 3

Tags: select, onclick, openlayers-3, double-click

I would like to click and double-click select features at the same time in openlayers 3. The *condition* option when creating ol.interaction.Select takes only one function, so a workaround is necessary

I tried writing my own custom condition function that calls the appropriate function, I was thinking of something like...

```
this.selectType = (feature) => {
      if (feature){
        if(feature.onclick){
          return ol.events.condition.singleClick
        } else {
          return ol.events.condition.doubleClick
        }
      }
    }

this.selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
      condition: this.selectType(),
      toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
      layers: this.layerFilter,
      features: this.features,
      style: this.selectStyle,
    });
```

...but without success.

I realize, I could create two separate interactions for selecting features, but would rather not because that would involve replicating a lot of code depending on the Select interaction.

Does anyone know if this is even possible in openlayers and how to handle a situation like this?

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is a function which takes a map browser event and returns a boolean.  Based on Alt+Cick in the OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/select-features.html to select on either single or double click you will need something like

```
this.selectType = (mapBrowserEvent) => {
          return ol.events.condition.singleClick(mapBrowserEvent) ||
              ol.events.condition.doubleClick(mapBrowserEvent);
    }

this.selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
      condition: this.selectType, // pass the function, don't call it!
      toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
      layers: this.layerFilter,
      features: this.features,
      style: this.selectStyle,
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mike, it works, though since this defines a mapBrowserEvent, double click zoom is now disabled. Will try to find a way of calling double click select only when there are features at the cursor

Comment: Both single and double work when I edit the example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QRKMRe

Comment: Yes, I confirm that your solution works. but it disables the double click zoom on map, which I would like to include as well

Comment: `condition: ol.events.condition.click` would do that

Comment: Thanks @Mike now I have what I need